# How to Get Worker Process ID(W3wp.exe) of Specific Sharepoint Application Pool(Not List of All)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am using the below command to find w3wp.exe ID, which I have to attach in debugging, but it gives all W3wp.exe list

C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd list wp.

I want to find only Specific 'Application Pool' w3wp.exe ID. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below command to find with w3wp.exe ID with apppoolName

**APPCMD list wps /apppool.name:AppPoolName**

There are more commands [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe)

I hope this helps

[image]

[image]

Comment: APPCMD list wp "WriteIDHere" return application Pool name.

But I have to Find W3wp from Sharepoint Application Pool or Sharepoint Application?

Comment: APPCMD list wps /apppool.name:DefaultAppPool                                                                                    instead of "DeafultAppPoo"l write app pool guid

Comment: can you share an example on this?

Comment: I have said that with your new answer my purpose has been solved and for answer it needs more reputaion(15).